# Apache Virtual Host with HTTP and HTTPS without duplicating the configuration

Tags: apache-http-server, ssl

how can I create a vhost for HTTP AND HTTPS in Apache without dupicating the configuration like

```
<VirtualHost mysite:80> 
  <Directory "/Users/myusername/sitefolder"> 
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    AllowOverride All 
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory> 
  DocumentRoot "/Users/myusername/sitefolder"
  ServerName mysite
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost mysite:443> 
  <Directory "/Users/myusername/sitefolder"> 
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    AllowOverride All 
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory> 
  DocumentRoot "/Users/myusername/sitefolder"
  ServerName mysite
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /Users/myusername/certs/server.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /Users/myusername/certs/server.key
</VirtualHost>
```

?

Mebus

Comment: I believe only a single IP/name could be assigned for an https:: connection.  Thus per IP number you can have only one website name.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [mod_macro](http://people.apache.org/~fabien/mod_macro/).

You create a macro and then define virtual hosts with it. Example from the site:

```
## Define a VHost Macro for repetitive configurations

<Macro VHost $host $port $dir>
  Listen $port
  <VirtualHost *:$port>

    ServerName $host
    DocumentRoot $dir

    <Directory $dir>
      # do something here...
    </Directory>

    # limit access to intranet subdir.
    <Directory $dir/intranet>
      order deny,allow
      deny from all
      allow from 10.0.0.0/8
    </Directory>
  </VirtualHost>
</Macro>

## Use of VHost with different arguments.

Use VHost www.apache.org 80 /projects/apache/web
Use VHost www.perl.com 8080 /projects/perl/web
Use VHost www.ensmp.fr 1234 /projects/mines/web
```

Comment: I came to say exactly this.  I'm pleased to see the use of mod_macro is not as obscure as I thought it was !

Comment: Another option, if you're using a configuration management tool like [Ansible](http://ansibleworks.com/), is to define a template (e.g. using [Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/)) that will print multiple vhost entries with supplied variables.